# Sorting Array Class not working

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, methods

I wrote a class that is supposed to create a random array, and sort it. I wrote the methods for each of these, and the code in each method works on its own. But when i use them together, i can't get the sort method to sort what the random method created. Any ideas?

Note, I'm coding in Java and using NetBeans, if that helps. And i do not want easier ways to code, i just want help making it work.

Here is my code.

```
public class SortUtility {

    private int[] num;
    static Random rand = new Random();
    private int c = 0;
    private int swap = 0;
    private int compare = 0;
    private int p = 10;
    private int[] b;
    //private int[] ex;

    public SortUtility() {
        num = new int[p];

    }

    public SortUtility(int[] Startnum) {
        int[] b = Startnum;
    }

    public int[] createRandomArray(int max, int min, int[] num) {
        //private int [10] ex;
        int [] ex = new int[num.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = rand.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            ex[i] = num[i];
        }

        return ex;
    }

    public int[] sortArray1(int[] ex) {
        int a;
        printItems();

        do {
            c++;
            for (a = 0; a < num.length - 1; a++) {
                compare++;
                if (num[a] > num[a + 1]) {
                    int temp = num[a];
                    num[a] = num[a + 1];
                    num[a + 1] = temp;
                    swap++;
                    System.out.println(num[2]);
                }
            }
            printItems();
        } while (c != num.length);

        return num;
    }

    public void printItems() {
        System.out.print("\nPass " + c + " Compares " + compare + " Swaps " + swap + " " + "items ");
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public int[] sortArray2(int[] ex) {
        int a;
        int swap2 = 0;
        printItems();

        do {
            c++;
            for (a = 0; a < num.length - 1 - (c - 1); a++) {
                compare++;
                if (num[a] > num[a + 1]) {
                    int temp = num[a];
                    num[a] = num[a + 1];
                    num[a + 1] = temp;
                    swap++;
                }
            }
            if (swap2 < swap && swap2 != swap) {
                if (swap2 < swap) {
                    swap2 = swap;
                }
            }
            swap2++;
            printItems();
        } while (swap + 2 != swap2);

        return num;
    }
}
```

And here is my client

```
package sortclient;

public class SortClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = {25, 7, 99, 14, 55, 3, 47, 6, 1};
        SortUtility ds = new SortUtility();
        //SortUtility j = new SortUtility(l);
        SortUtility ab = new SortUtility();
        int[] a = ab.createRandomArray(99, 0, num);

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    ab.sortArray1(a);

    }
}
```

And here is the results when i run the client:

```
run:
52
8
82
87
93
29
94
33
46

Pass 0 Compares 0 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 1 Compares 9 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 2 Compares 18 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 3 Compares 27 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 4 Compares 36 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 5 Compares 45 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 6 Compares 54 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 7 Compares 63 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 8 Compares 72 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 9 Compares 81 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Pass 10 Compares 90 Swaps 0 items 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0     seconds)
```

Which proves the random array method works and the sort kinda works

Comment: You print out the random array and afterwards you are sorting it, did you forget a second print out?

Comment: You have major variable name confusion here. In the sort method for example you take an array called `ex` and then print and sort one called `num`. In the creation method you take a local array called `num` which shadows your class variable, populate that and copy it to another local array called `ex`. The reason your code does not work it because you are using the wrong variable in almost every place. Read about scope and shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have written is wrong. First of all change

```
     public SortUtility(int[] Startnum) {
        int[] b = Startnum;
    }

to:
    public SortUtility(int[] Startnum) {
    num = Startnum;
    }

and then
```

change the method signature of createRandomArray to:

```
    public int[] createRandomArray(int max, int min)
```

The change in createRandomArray is required because you are filling an array in different object and trying to sort a different array object. 
The change in constructor is warranted because you were allocating array space for a constructor local object which is useless.

Use the following modified code for your reference.

```
     import java.util.Random;


public class SortClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = {25, 7, 99, 14, 55, 3, 47, 6, 1};
        SortUtility ds = new SortUtility();
        //SortUtility j = new SortUtility(l);
        SortUtility ab = new SortUtility(num);
        int[] a = ab.createRandomArray(99, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        ab.sortArray1(a);




    }
}

 class SortUtility {

private int[] num;
static Random rand = new Random();
private int c = 0;
private int swap = 0;
private int compare = 0;
private int p = 10;
private int[] b;
//private int[] ex;

public SortUtility() {
    num = new int[p];

}

public SortUtility(int[] Startnum) {
    num = Startnum;
}

public int[] createRandomArray(int max, int min) {
    //private int [10] ex;
    int [] ex = new int[num.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        num[i] = rand.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        ex[i] = num[i];
    }
    return ex;
}

public int[] sortArray1(int[] ex) {
    int a;
    printItems();
    do {
        c++;
        for (a = 0; a < num.length - 1; a++) {
            compare++;
            if (num[a] > num[a + 1]) {
                int temp = num[a];
                num[a] = num[a + 1];
                num[a + 1] = temp;
                swap++;
                System.out.println(num[2]);
            }
        }
        printItems();
    } while (c != num.length);
    return num;
}

public void printItems() {
    System.out.print("\nPass " + c + " Compares " + compare + " Swaps " + swap + " " + "items ");
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
    }
}

public int[] sortArray2(int[] ex) {
    int a;
    int swap2 = 0;
    printItems();
    do {
        c++;
        for (a = 0; a < num.length - 1 - (c - 1); a++) {
            compare++;
            if (num[a] > num[a + 1]) {
                int temp = num[a];
                num[a] = num[a + 1];
                num[a + 1] = temp;
                swap++;
            }
        }
        if (swap2 < swap && swap2 != swap) {
            if (swap2 < swap) {
                swap2 = swap;
            }
        }
        swap2++;
        printItems();
    } while (swap + 2 != swap2);
    return num;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class SortUtility, there is a method called "sortArray1". Note that it receives as parameters an array named "ex". Also, note it performs the sorting over "num" array (num is initialized with 0's). So, your methods are working but the sorting is being done over an array with 0's and not over the array you just received as parameter.

So, in order to make them work together properly, in the aforementioned method change the references from "num" array to "ex" array.

Finally, the aforementioned method, after changes, is:

```
public int[] sortArray1(int[] ex) {
    int a;
    printItems();
    do {
        c++;
        for (a = 0; a < ex.length - 1; a++) {
            compare++;
            if (ex[a] > ex[a + 1]) {
                int temp = ex[a];
                ex[a] = ex[a + 1];
                ex[a + 1] = temp;
                swap++;
                System.out.println(ex[2]);
            }
        }
        printItems();
    } while (c != ex.length);
    return ex;
}
```

Please, see if the changes will have any side effects on your logic.

P.s.: you're using bubble sort that is slow. Consider using merge sort, heap sort and quick sort. Check this site http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ out.

Answer (score 0):

From first glance your method

```
 public int[] sortArray1(int[] ex) {
    int a;
    printItems();
    do {
        c++;
        for (a = 0; a < num.length - 1; a++) {
            compare++;
            if (num[a] > num[a + 1]) {
                int temp = num[a];
                num[a] = num[a + 1];
                num[a + 1] = temp;
                swap++;
                System.out.println(num[2]);
            }
        }
        printItems();
    } while (c != num.length);
    return num;
}
```

in SortUtility is not using the provided array parameter **ex**, and you are sorting the internal array (it's another question why you keep it, and then try to sort over a different passed array). A quick fix would be to just add

```
  num = ex;
```

before your sorting loop. Note that that way your original array that you passed will be sorted (as it will point to the same internal referent), so if you want to preserve it replace

```
  num = ex;
```

with

```
  System.arraycopy(ex, 0, num, 0, ex.length);
```